# Any difference between String.getOrElse() and String.elementAtOrElse()?

Tags: kotlin

As the title states:

Is there any difference between [`String.getOrElse()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/get-or-else.html) and [`String.elementAtOrElse()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/element-at-or-else.html)? From a functional point of view they seem completely identical, maybe some performance difference?

Same question accounts to [`String.getOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/get-or-null.html) and [`String.elementAtOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/element-at-or-null.html).

Comment: Great question! It would be interesting to hear the history behind this. My bet is on some arcane old compatibility layers with JVM or JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the implementation in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blame/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Strings.kt they look identical.

```
/**
 * Returns a character at the given [index] or the result of calling the [defaultValue] function if the [index] is out of bounds of this char sequence.
 * 
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Elements.elementAtOrElse
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun CharSequence.elementAtOrElse(index: Int, defaultValue: (Int) -> Char): Char {
    return if (index >= 0 && index <= lastIndex) get(index) else defaultValue(index)
}
```

```
/**
 * Returns a character at the given [index] or the result of calling the [defaultValue] function if the [index] is out of bounds of this char sequence.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun CharSequence.getOrElse(index: Int, defaultValue: (Int) -> Char): Char {
    return if (index >= 0 && index <= lastIndex) get(index) else defaultValue(index)
}
```

I hope somebody else can provide details about the history of this.

Answer (score 11):

To explain the why:

From the issue that added these over at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6952 it appears that `elementAtOrElse()` was added first and named such for compatibility with `Iterable`s, while `getOrElse()` was added later for compatibility with `List`s.

Answer (score 4):

The very links you included in your question allow you to see the source code of each implementation which tells you that, no, there is no difference.

In fact `elementAtOrNull` literally just calls `getOrNull`.

Comment: Thanks, seems that I ignored the `(source)` button on the documentation pages all the time.